# New Google Chrome console does not differentiate updated logged objects

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, console

I'm running Version 23.0.1271.64

One of these last updates updated the web developer view in Google Chrome.

Many features are nice, but the updates to the Console seem to be broken.

If you have an object

```
var object = {'one':true, 'two':false}
```

and `console.log(object)`

then make a change on object

```
object.one = false
```

and `console.log(object)` again (say after a click event)

The change will not be reflected, the console will simply increment the counter next to the object name.

Is this a bug or is it a new 'feature'?  The old console would reflect object updates.

Comment: Strange. I believe there was a change made so that the output of console.log didn't change after it was logged, but that _shouldn't_ affect this... however, this doesn't happen when just typing `object` into the console.

Comment: probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/, maybe file a bug